# Azure AD B2C - filter list of countries options on MFA page of sign up v2 flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I've created Sign up v2 user flow in B2C with multifactor authentication enabled.

Is it possible to filter the list of countries on the MFA page. I only want to allow registrations in AU (+61) and NZ (+64), so ideally all the other country options can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using Language Customization.

1. Go to SignupV2 userflow and click on "Languages" at the bottom in left blade.
2. Enable Language customization
3. Click configured tab, and then click English. A pane will open on the right
4. download defaults for Multifactor authentication at the bottom,
5. modify json element with string Id "countryList" to your desired list. set override = true

upload the defaults back run the user flow.

Learn more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization